# .htaccess file: is it possible to specify sub-directory location for rules?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

My old website was built by handcoding HTML and has the directory structure:

```
public_html
   .htaccess
   index.html
   ...
   content_folder
   docs_folder
      .htaccess
      doc1.html
      doc2.html
      doc3.html
   ...
```

My new website is built using a CMS that stores its webpages in a database and so there is no traditional website directory structure like that shown above.

The `public_html/docs_folder/.htaccess` file above contains the following rules:

```
# Only permit access from links coming from my website (e.g.http://www.mydomain.com).
SetEnvIf Referer http://www.mydomain.com internal 
<Files *> 
   order Deny,Allow 
   Deny from all 
   Allow from env=internal 
</Files>
```

Since there's no directory structure in the new website, I wonder if there's anyway I can include the `public_html/docs_folder/.htaccess` rules above, which only apply to webpages in the `docs_folder` directory (and webpages in any sub-directories), inside the `public_html/.htaccess` file instead.

Is there a `<location>` attribute or other means to include a rule in an `.htaccess` file but have it apply to a sub-directory rather than the current directory the `.htaccess` file resides in?

Could someone give an example using the rule above?

Also, does `<Files *>` as used above cover all files (.html, .pdf, .css, etc.)? I'm hoping so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in the htaccess file in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://yourdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^docs_folder/ - [L,F]
```

You'll need to remove the htaccess file in your `/docs_folder/`

Comment: Thanks, but this rule looks different. Can you explain what it's doing? I want to block access to any file in the `public_html/docs_folder` except for links originating from my website. Not sure how this helps. There are a lot more directories than what I show above (it's just an example).

Comment: @ggkmath wasn't clear at all what you wanted, changed the rules based on your comment

Comment: Thanks, could you explain what each line is doing?

Comment: @ggkmath The first line turns on the rewrite engine, the second line is a condition which checks that the referer request header is *not* from your site (note that this can be easily forged), and the last line matches a request for the docs folder and denies access.